# Is my 12-hour power too high?

Tags: activity-monitor

In Activity Monitor, I'm seeing this:

[image]

Is 1k/900 too much power? I believe I know what is causing it-- but will this increase my power bill?

Thanks.

Comment: Chrome, a well-known resource hog, is causing it. I've no idea why it's so popular.

Answer (score 1):

That column for 12 hour power is supposed to be in watts. Using 1 thousand watts per 12 hours is not a lot of power.

That is about 2 kilowatt hours (**kwh**) a day. Your local power cost is likely between 9 cents (0.09 USD) to 50 cents (0.50 USD) per **kwh**. So that is costing you roughly $0.18 USD to $1 USD per day.

Comment: Do you have a source that the column is in watts? I haven't been able to find anything definitive, but most sources claim that the column is a unitless measure using a custom equation created by Apple.